# How to correctly send a localizable string to a printer?

Tags: swift, printing, localization

I had multiple working Localizable.strings files in my project. However, when I try to print some text using the printer, which concatenate some localizable strings, I can only get the English(the default language) output, even the device has changed to another language. How can I present a localizable string to a printer correctly? Below is an example how I print a localizable text.

```
let printController = UIPrintInteractionController.sharedPrintController()
let formatter = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: "Hello".localized)  //English only?
printController.printFormatter = formatter
printController.presentAnimated(true, completionHandler: nil)
```

The `.localized` is a String extension that'll return a localized string.

```
extension String {
    var localized: String {
        return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle(), value: "", comment: "")
    }
}
```

And of course, the following works in difference languages.

```
myLabel.text = "Hello".localized
```

Comment: Are you actually *getting* a localized string with that method? e.g., have you set breakpoints or inserted log statements to verify that you're getting what you expect? I suspect it's some problem with how your strings files are set up rather than your code.

Comment: @ReidBelton I print the same string display on my screen, but the screen display in localized language, the print out is English.